# Use ISO Level3/5 as modifier in vim keymap?

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout, input-methods

I've been using [the pseudo keymap solution from my previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2260/267) to great effect for 6 months now. The short version is that it allows me to keep the computer keyboard map in my usual [Programmer's Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) at almost all times but have an alternate insert mode in vim where I can type using a [Turkish-F layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Turkish_.28F-keyboard.29).

This is great for the alphabet and I've become pretty proficient in both languages, but it's an ongoing problem for symbols. The [Turkish alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_alphabet) has more characters than English and by necessity takes over more keys than the [Simplified Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) based layout I'm overlaying it on. The question becomes, **“Where can I even put the displaced symbols?”**

So far my solution has been to include a few extra mappings for that prefixes keys that were previously symbols with an Alt-code variant that restores the original symbol. If you're lost, and example would be what would be <kbd>Z</kbd> on a QWERTY keyboard. In DVP this has `'` and `"` (in Level 1/2 respectively). Now in my pseudo PTF mapping mode in vim `'` is remapped to `j` and `"` to `J` as that's where the Turkish-F layout has that letter. So far so good. But not where do I get my quotes from? By mapping `<A-'>` to `'` I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to get my quotes back in the position they would be in DVP even when my vim insert keymap is translating to PTF. Whew.

But the <kbd>Alt</kbd> is ① in a really bad place for this and ② conflicts with keybindings I would usually use for window management. I can, of course, move the key, but [I have it where it is](http://goo.gl/7GfaHu) for easy chording of keybindings. Using a different modifier would seem like a better solution. I have ISO Level3 (or Level5) Shift available in a great place for this. The only trouble is I can't figure out how to map them in Vim.

1. What can I put in [my keymap file](https://github.com/alerque/que-vim/blob/master/.vim/keymap/dvorak2turkishf.vim) to catch chorded key combos using Level3 Shift the way that `<C-a>` catches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or `<A-a>` catches <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>?

I suspect the answer to that is going to be, “You can't. Sucker.” In that event:

2. What *can* I do? Can I setup a dead-key equivalent in a vim keymap such that a tap on the dead key (which could be anything, my keyboard is programmable) preceding any key will cause that one key to skip the custom map an emit the original non-mapped key?

Comment: The answer to (1) is indeed that you can't in Vim (IIRC it's planned for Neovim). But you can in some terminal emulators: see the second half of http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/disable-esc-but-keep-c/3570#3570. What terminal emulator do you use? (If you use GVim, you're back to “sucker”.)

Comment: @Gilles I'm actually using Neovim (git HEAD version) in a tmux session in Termite (a VTE based terminal).

Comment: VTE? Nope, [sucker](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191527/bash-wrong-key-sequence-bindings-with-controlaltspace/191710#191710).